# The domain portion of the userPrincipalName property is invalid when I invoke New-AzureADuser @param

Tags: powershell

> New-AzureADUser @param
> |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> | Error occurred while executing NewUser  Code: Request_BadRequest Message: The domain portion of the userPrincipalName property is invalid. You must use one of the
> | verified domain names in your organization. RequestId: 6e8a6c15-8c49-4fce-913b-0313bd16feb7 DateTimeStamp: Mon, 26 Jul 2021 14:26:01 GMT Details: PropertyName  -
> | userPrincipalName, PropertyErrorCode  - InvalidValue HttpStatusCode: BadRequest HttpStatusDescription: Bad Request HttpResponseStatus: Completed

my jsonInput file contains:

{
"DisplayName": "lili Waters",
"AccountEnabled": true ,
"UserPrincipalName": "lili.waters@x.ca",
"MailNickName": "liliW",
"PasswordProfile":{
}
"GivenName":"Lili",
"SurName":"Waters"
}

Comment: So where is the code that resulted in this error message?

Comment: As Theo mentioned, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68532401/edit) and add the code that generated this error.

Comment: To be clear: `contoso.com` in `lili.waters@contoso.com` is an _example_ domain name.

In your real data, you must use a domain name that belongs to your organization.

Comment: I did put my company domain name and still get same error

Comment: my json file contains the following: 

{
   "DisplayName": "lili Waters",
   "AccountEnabled": true ,
   "UserPrincipalName": "lili.waters@x.ca", 
   "MailNickName": "liliW",
   "passwordProfile": {
       "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
       "password": "xxyyzz"
   }
   "GivenName":"Lili",
   "SurName":"Waters" 
}


$param =@{}

foreach ($J in $jsonInput.PSObject.Properties){
  $param.UserPrincipleName =$j.Value
  
}
New-AzureADUser @param